# Emoji Picker in Slack-Clone Project

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, slack, emoji

In my slack clone there is a chat input field. I followed a simple tutorial on adding emoji picker (emoji-mart).
[chat input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNWNG.png)

Yet, when i click the emoji icon it pop up the emoji picker window within the container where the emoji icon is. (so inside the chat input container while changing its height to contain the emoji window).
[emoji picker window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hWsr.png)

my question is, how can i make it pop up above the chat input and not inside it just like the original one in the picture. is it a styling matter or do i have to add any special functionality??
[emoji window correct way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWpvO.png)

code for only chat input:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import SendIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Send';
import {ChatInputIconsData} from '../data/ChatInputIcons'
import {ChatIconsInputData} from '../data/ChatInputIcons'
import EmojiEmotionsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/EmojiEmotions';
import "emoji-mart/css/emoji-mart.css";
import { Picker } from "emoji-mart";
import {useState} from 'react'


function ChatInput() {

    const [emojiPickerState, SetEmojiPicker] = useState(false);
    const [message, SetMessage] = useState("");

    let emojiPicker;
    if (emojiPickerState) {
        emojiPicker = (
        <Picker
            title="Pick your emoji…"
            emoji="point_up"
            onSelect={emoji => SetMessage(message + emoji.native)}
        />
        );
    }

    function triggerPicker(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        SetEmojiPicker(!emojiPickerState);
    }

    return (
        <Container>
            <InputContainer>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Message here..."  value={message}
                    onChange={event => SetMessage(event.target.value)} />
                </form>
                <IconsContainer>
                    <LeftIcons>
                        {
                        ChatInputIconsData.map(item => (
                            <LeftIconsItem>
                                {item.icon}
                            </LeftIconsItem>
                        ))
                        }
                    </LeftIcons>
                    <RightIcons>
                        {
                        ChatIconsInputData.map(item => (
                            <RightIconsItem>
                                {item.icon}
                            </RightIconsItem>
                        ))
                        }
                        {emojiPicker}
                        <Emoji onClick={triggerPicker}/>
                        <SendButton>
                            <Send />
                        </SendButton>
                    </RightIcons>
                </IconsContainer>
            </InputContainer>
        </Container>
    );
}

export default ChatInput


const Container = styled.div`
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 24px;
`;

const InputContainer = styled.div`
    border: 1px solid #8D8D8E;
    border-radius: 4px;

    form {
        display: flex; 
        height: 42px; 
        align-items: center;
        padding-left: 10px;
        input {
            flex: 1;
            border: none;
            font-size: 13px;
        }
        input:focus{
            outline: none;
        }
    }
`;

const IconsContainer = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: rgba(var(--sk_foreground_min_solid,248,248,248),1);
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(83, 39, 83, .13); 
    overflow: visible;
`;

const LeftIcons = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
`;
const LeftIconsItem = styled.div`
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #606060;
`;

const RightIcons = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
`;

const RightIconsItem = styled.div`
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #606060;
    
`;

const Emoji = styled(EmojiEmotionsIcon)`
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #606060;
`;

const SendButton = styled.div`
    background: #007a5a;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;

    .MuiSvgIcon-root {
        width: 18px;
    }

    :hover {
        background: #148567;
    }
`;

const Send = styled(SendIcon)`
    color: #D9D9D9;
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

ok solved: added a style position: absolute with bottom and right 20px to my Picker tag and it works just perefect!
[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76oHx.png)

Answer (score 0):

**You need to Use Css**

Types of Methods You can use :

Positions :

```
.EmojiPicker {
position: relative / absolute;
top: -30px;
right: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;    
}
```

Margin:

```
.element {
  margin-bottom: 10px; // THIS WILL CHANGE OTHER CLASSES SO USE POSITIONS
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping, but am not quite sure how to apply your hint in my code, tried few thing but it does not change what i want to change

Comment: @Amir This is how you can Apply this code . 1. You must fist select the Div element Which all the content is in it, like the emojis and other stuff 2. Go to your browsers Inspect element and Select that parent class then add position: relative; and then the top: -30px; If you would like you can change this using your computers up and down arrow keys

Comment: ok solved it a bit differently, added a style position: absolute with bottom and right 20px to my Picker tag and it works just perefect!